# Time Value of Money (Future Value/Annuity)

Tags: finance

[image]

So I found this popular solution online (in the image above, below the question) and I was wondering why they chose this process.

I think I get the process for the solution above but does my attempt work as well?

**My Attempt:**

When I saw the problem I thought about calculating the **Future Value of $$60,000 over 10 years @ 10% interest** and comparing it to the **Future Value of Annuity of a $10,000 payment over 10 years @ 10% interest**.

I can show calculations, but isnt this method more straight forward?

Comment: Well, I don't understand why you would compute the future value of the annuity at all.  Just get the present value, which is $10\times (d+ d+d^2+\cdots +d^{10})$ where $d$ is the discount factor $\frac 1{1.1}$.  This works out to about $61.45K$ which is greater than $60K$.

Comment: They're equivalent. For the annuity, the work is the same. They divide that the future value of the annuity by $(1.1)^{10}$ and compare the result to $60$, whereas you multiply $60$ by $(1.1)^{10}$ and compare the result to the future value of the annuity. Same work.

Comment: @quasi  I expect your reading is correct.  I already edited my comment accordingly.

Comment: @mathguy: But lulu's suggested method is simpler still.

Comment: I was just thinking I could compare the future value of a lump sum with the future value of an annuity instead of finding the present value of annuity and comparing it with 60,000

Comment: How did you get the future value of the annuity?

Comment: Note: They didn't find the present value of the annuity. They found the present value of the _future_ _value_ of the annuity, and that _is_ a lump sum.

Comment: i got the FVA = 10,000 ( (1.1)^10  - 1 ) / 0.1 )

Comment: Same as what they did, no?

Comment: Yes actually, but I guess I thought it was easier to calculate the FV of 60,000 instead of calculating the PV of the FVA

Comment: Thus, your method of calculating FVA is identical to theirs. The took FVA, divided it by $(1.1)^{10}$ and compared it to $60$. One division, one comparison. You took $60$, multiplied it by $(1.1)^{10}$, and compared it to FVA. One multiplication, one comparison.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67797/discussion-between-mathguy-and-quasi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @quasi

> "your method of calculating FVA is identical to theirs. The took FVA,
>   divided it by (1.1)10(1.1)10 and compared it to 6060. One division,
>   one comparison. You took 6060, multiplied it by (1.1)10(1.1)10, and
>   compared it to FVA. One multiplication, one comparison."